# Is there a way in Jackson to check if a JSON string compatible with a POJO?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json string and two different classes with different properties. Classes looks like this:

### Student

studentId

name

surname

gpa

Getters/Setters

### Teacher

teacherId

name

surname

Getters/Setters

Now I get a json string and I need a function to return boolean value if the json string is compatible with the object model.

So json might be like this:

```
{studentId: 1213, name: Mike, surname: Anderson, gpa: 3.0}
```

I need a function to return true to something like this:

```
checkObjectCompatibility(json, Student.class);
```

Comment: what library have been used u to parse? I think you should use object mapper if u know the keys of `JSONObject` I will provide u a solution to deserialize into a pojo either using `ObjectMapper` or `GOOGLE GSON`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if a json string is not compatible with a class.

```
mapper.readValue(jsonStr, Student.class);
```

method throws JsonMappingException

so you can create a method and call readValue method and use try-catch block to catch the JsonMappingException to return false, and otherwise return true.

Something like this;

```
public boolean checkJsonCompatibility(String jsonStr, Class<?> valueType) throws JsonParseException, IOException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            mapper.readValue(jsonStr, valueType);
            return true;
        } catch (JsonParseException | JsonMappingException e) {
            return false;
        } 

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to achieve that would be with trial and error :

```
boolean isA(String json, Class expected) {
  try {
     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     mapper.readValue(json, expected);
     return true;
  } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     return false;
  } 
}
```

but i strongly suggest to deal with the problem in a more structured way, i.e. try not to rely on trial and error.